# How to configure Auth0 callback for custom domain in netlify?

Tags: auth0, netlify

I just launched a React app on Netlify. I have an issue with my Auth0 integration in the app. In Auth0, I've added my custom domain name to the list of allowed callback URLs, but I get an error when I try to sign in, saying:

```
Callback URL mismatch.
The URL "https://<blah long url here>.netlify.com/callback" is not in the list of allowed callback URLs.
```

I've tried adding that URL, but then on sign in, the app actually redirects to that long Netlify URL instead of my custom domain.
Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for Auth0.

From the error it seems that the application is sending `https://APP_ID.netlify.com/callback` as a callbackUrl instead of your custom domain url. You'll need to set your custom domain as your callbackUrl in Auth0.js' (or our other SDKs) redirectUri instead of the `https://APP_ID.netlify.com/callback` when using custom domains!